# Catching and relaying show toast event

Tags: lightning-out, toast

We want to use Lightning toasts from Lightning Out. We want to do this using the standard `new ShowToastEvent` approach, so our components will work identically either in Lightning Experience or Lighting Out.

Our naive plan was to set up a listener on our VF page in which the Lightning Out component runs, catch the `lightning__showtoast` event, then pass it to the iframe parent using `postMessage`, listen for the `message` event in a top-level Ligthning component such as one running in the utility bar, retrieving the parameters, and then re-issuing the `new ShowToastEvent` event.

This all worked--almost. What we found is that when the listener on the VF page picks up the event, its parameters (`title`, `message`, `mode` etc.) are nowhere to be found--not in the `detail` field of the event, or anyw3here else. This is the case whether the component setting up the listener is an LWC or an Aura component. I have consulted the built-in file `toastManager.js`, which seems to be retrieveing the toast attributes by simply saying `event.toastAttributes`, but when I do that I just get `undefined`. A little bit of detective work reveals that `new ShowToastEvent` does some magic with "secure events", and places the parameters in this `toastAttributes` field, but that is not visible by the time the event arrives at the VF page listener.

How can I catch a `lighting__showtoast` event with the toast attributes intact so I can access them?

Comment: I got this to work by setting the API version of the component trying to access `event.toastAttributes` to 39.0 in order to disable Locker Service, but have no idea what unintended consequences that might lead to.